# Dumping mysql database adds 'DEFAULT NULL'

Tags: mysql, database

I'm ramping on mysql db handling and migration, and while trying the dump and restore commands I came across the following issue:
While my database was populated with data created by usage, I dumped a table from it using the following command:

```
mysqldump --defaults-file='path_to_my.cnf' my_table_name > backup.sql
```

I then created a new database, from the same source code (hence- same schema), and loaded the backup using:

```
mysql  --defaults-file='path_to_my.cnf' my_table_name < backup.sql
```

I then dumped the new database in order to make sure I got the same results (I wanted to make sure that dumping db that was populated from regular usage, will be exactly like dumping it after loading a backup file).
I got pretty much the same results, except for this:

```
<   `some_field_id` int(11), // Regular use DB
---
>   `some_field_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, // Loaded backup-file DB
```

This happened to several fields, which are ForeignKey fields, that were defined in the model using 'null=True'. I understand that the 'DEFAULT NULL' is probably suppose to be in this backup file, but I can't understand why it wasn't included in the original file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `DEFAULT NULL` is the normal behavior for nullable, not specified columns of a row to insert. You wrote about migration: Are there differences in version and configuration of your source and destination databases?

Comment: No, I'm designing a migration process and as a part of that, I tried to backup and restore at the simple case- without changing the schema. I then noticed the diff in the 2 dump files, and wondered why exactly that occurred, i.e- why isn't the first one also include 'DEFAULT NULL' ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the schema but the DBMS. Are there differences in the `my.ini` files and which mysql server versions are involved?

Comment: No, nothing. Everything is exactly the same except for 1 thing- the first case is db with populated data (from regular usage), while the second got the data from a backup file (the same backup file that was dumped from the first db).

Comment: Thanks for you quick responses btw @ChrisTophski

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not very familiar with `mysql`'s and `mysqldump`'s arguments. Please have a look at the docs for possibly some arguments regarding text formatting or handling of defaults. Have you tried the import statement without `--defaults-file` argument?

Comment: I haven't tried it without the file, but I don't think it will matter. I will take your advice and search the docs. Thanks again!